# Usage of multiple trigger statements

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers

What are triggers in mysql. And how to use triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several good reasons to use triggers, for example to:

1. Populate column values automatically.
2. Enforce complex integrity constraints.
3. Enforce complex business rules.
4. Maintain replicate tables.
5. Audit data modification.

However, triggers can sometimes be a maintenance headache The worst case scenario I have come across is that a trigger was accidentally disabled. In your example that would mean that stock and money transactions would not get updated when a purchased is made without any form of warning or error. I also have seen databases where triggers get chained across multiple tables and that make debugging quite complex.

Comment: Thank you so much.. now I got a better understanding..